# Is there any View which supports multi-touch zoom other than ImageView?

Tags: android, view, touch, zooming

I have been searching for a view with multi-touch zoom. Couldn't find anything other than ImageView.

I would like a view which will zoom all its children on multi-touch gesture.
How can I do this?

Thanks

PS: I do not want to use webview.

Comment: Have you looked into creating a custom view?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a custom class of the view you want to take the multitouch on
and overide ontouch events and write your own interface on ontouch to give call back to the code where you want to implement  multitouch